# Keep the Favorite File/Folder on Top in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management

Windows **Quick Access** feature allows to set some folders as favorites and it shows up on the top on the left hand sidebar.

However, often, you are working on some folders and you would like to "**favorite**" some files or folders, which would always show up on the top. Is it possible? I often do 'Sort by Date Modified' or 'Sort by Name'. But, it would be nice to have few files/folders that you can set as favorites, that would override all those settings, so it always shows up on top. Please check the screenshot below. Is there a way to achieve this feature? Thank you.

[image: windows file explorer favorites]

Comment: I do not see your setup in File Explorer. It looks like a screen shot from Edge (browser)

Comment: @John this is my Windows File Explorer, it is not screenshot from MS Edge. I have it grouped by date modified. You can see the list of files. I added the *red* items on the top  to show the feature I am requesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer has no such option.

You could perhaps look for an alternative third-party product, although the
chances are very slim that any of them has implemented such an option.

See the article
[The 10 Best Windows File Explorer Alternatives and Replacements](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/best-windows-file-explorer-replacements/).

Comment: I have looked into Q-Dir and it does not have this. Do others thinks there is a value in this kind of feature? @harrymc

Comment: The chances are very slim. I have never seen such a product advertised.